check udp socket is connected or not
given a socket file descriptor, is it possible to check if a UDP socket is connected or not?
int sock_fd = -1;

void create_socket() {
   if ((sock_fd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0)) == -1) {
       perror("udp socket() failed");
       exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
   }
}

sockaddr_in create_sock_addr(const char* ip, const uint16_t port) {
   sockaddr_in sock_addr{};
   sock_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
   sock_addr.sin_port = htons(port);
    
   if (inet_aton(ip, &sock_addr.sin_addr) == 0) {
       perror("udp inet_aton() failed");
       exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
   }

   return sock_addr;
}

void connect_socket(const char* ip, const uint16_t port) {
   const sockaddr_in sock_addr = create_sock_addr(ip, port);
   if (connect(sock_fd, (const sockaddr*)&sock_addr, sizeof(sockaddr_in)) == -1) {
      perror("udp connect() failed");
      exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
   }
}

bool is_sock_connected() {
   // check sock_fd is connected or not
   return true;
}

int main() {
   create_socket();
   connect_socket("127.0.0.1", 12345);
   if (is_sock_connected()) {
       // use send() function to send data
   } else {
       // use sendto() function to send data
   }

   close(sock_fd);
}


Try getpeername() and see whether it returns an error (ENOTCONN).
